# Template without application.hbs as root?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I've got an Ember-Cli App and would like to create an admin-interface for my application which looks nothing like the page set up in application.hbs.

How do I make the admin-interface independent from that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I achieved it was to have the `base` route and, in your case, `admin` route, kind of what @jcbvm was saying. So the router would look like:

```
this.resource('base', {
  path: '/'
}, function() {

  this.path('my-route');

  // the rest of the app
});

this.resource('admin', {
  path: '/admin'
}, function() {
  // admin part
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can hardly be achieved, my best bet is to either creating a separate application for your admin interface or by moving your core application to a separate route.

When moving your core application to a separate route, you can move the contents of your application.hbs to the template of the new route and your admin interface to the admin route. The only drawback of this is that you will always see the name of your core route in the URL when going to the core application.

Answer (score 1):

You should likely go down the path of Ember CLI addons, see [here](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-admin)